# How to deploy react vite project with .env file to github

Tags: reactjs, vite

My local JSON server is `http://localhost:3000` and I create a **.env.development** file. In this file

```
VITE_ENV = development

VITE_API_URL = http://localhost:3030
```

This is my project code
https://github.com/hninyushwee/react-blog-page

This is my hosting preview
https://hninyushwee.github.io/react-blog-page/

I deployed this project to GitHub page but all data cannot be seen and cannot add new data

How to deploy my project .env file with JSON server

Answer (score 1):

You can't deploy json-server to GitHub pages.

json-server requires nodejs to work